# How to display more number of points on a static google map. Error 414

Tags: google-maps

I want to display routes on a map by connecting two points with a line. I successfully achieved this like this

[image].

But my problem i have 50 locations to be displayed. When i try to display the image i am getting an error message in my browser

```
"The url is too large to handle. Error 414. That's all we know".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put simply; you need to make the URL shorter somehow. Static Map URLs are [restricted to 2048 characters](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Limits) in size.

If you are using a text encoding data format, remove leading zeros from numbers, remove trailing zeros after decimal points, and round or truncate the numbers after decimal points.
If that does not shorten the URL enough, use simple (1 character) or extended (2 character) encoding.